# How can i dynamically replace a widget without opening a new page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

hello I want when I click button for example to stay in the same page but view another screen in specific container without duplicating page with different content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an enum with the current selected page.

```
enum CurrentPage {
HomePage,
LoginPage,
RegisterPage,
}
```

Declare a variable to save the current selected page:

```
CurrentPage currentPage = CurrentPage.HomePage;
```

When you click on a button you change the current page:

```
onPressed: (){
setState(() {
      currentPage = CurrentPage.RegisterPage;
    });
}
```

In your code you ask for the current state and accordingly you change the widget:

```
Widget content = Container();

switch (currentPage) {
     
     case CurrentPage.HomePage:
        content = HomePage();
       break;
     case CurrentPage.LoginPage:
       content = LoginPage();
       break;
     ....
   }
```

And this widget is placed in your Widget Tree.